# SQL Server authentication failed in Visual Studio for DDBC CHECKPRIMARYFILE

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, authentication

I have a SQL Server DB by the name of "c:\place\name.mdf" accessed by a ASP.NET WebForms application in Visual Studio. Authentication is done using SQL Server authentication (rather than Microsoft authentication) via a specific user/password. This worked fine until I have accidentally deleted the DB connection in Vsual Studio server explorer view, and when trying to reattach it, I got an error that

> user does not have privileges to execute `DDBC CHECKPRIMARYFILE`.

The user has `db_owner` permission, the mdf file is accessible, I can even manage to execute `DBCC CHECKDB`, but still `CHECKPRIMARYFILE` fails.
For example - in SQL following login by the specific user in SQL Server authentication:

```
use [c:\place\name.mdf];
go
SELECT IS_MEMBER('db_owner') AS IsDbOwner; -> yields 1
DBCC CHECKPRIMARYFILE ('c:\place\name.mdf'); -> fails.
```

Comment: `DDBC CHECKPRIMARYFILE` is undocumented, I'm guessing it requires `sysadmin` permissions. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/248664/user-guest-does-not-have-permission-to-run-dbcc-checkprimaryfile-smss says you need `CREATE DATABASE` permissions, normally only given to `sysadmin` for security reasons.